# Django getting information from three related tables. Joining tables

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have three tables that are related.

```
class Book(models.Model):
  year_published = models.IntField()
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

class Author(models.Model):
  author_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  agent = models.ForeignKey(LitAgent)

class LitAgent(models.Model):
  agent_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Ok, I can get a `LitAgent` like so

```
getla = LitAgent.objects.get(agent_id=1)
```

I can get the `authors` like so

```
getauthors = Author.objects.filter(agent=getla.agent_id)
```

But how can I get all the books that an author has too and make sure the `books` line up to the right author? I also need access to the data in `LitAgent` and `Author` too

Comment: please provide your models.py and describe how do you get models in view.

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding, you want to get the books by using an agent_id. If this is what you want then you can accomplish this using

```
books = Book.objects.filter(author__agent__agent_id=1)
```

This will return a list of all books that the author related to the agent with id = 1. If you want to access the author for each book you can use

```
for book in books:
    print book.author.name
    # in order to print the author agent 
    print book.author.agent.name
```

---

On the other side you can reach the books from the `LitAgent` model.

Lets say

```
agent = LitAgent.objects.get(agent_id=1)
```

Then to get the authors it will be

```
authors = agent.author_set.all()
```

Now you can iterate

```
for author in authors:
    for book in author.book_set.all()
         print book
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for. You saved me again Othman. Thanks.

Comment: It was very helpful. Thanks.